# How to have event configuration with string for GitHub Actions On?

Tags: github, github-actions

I have the following GitHub Actions YML file.

```
name: CI
on:
  - push
  - release:
    - types: [published]
#...
```

But I'm getting an error: `Invalid Workflow File` `Invalid type for on`.

The only other way to do what I want here is to do `on: [push, release]`. But then I can't filter by type `published`.

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The yaml doesn't look valid to me. Try this:

```
name: CI
on:
  push:
  release:
    types: [published]
```